# Reading "Shigyonot" as insanity - Ramak Or Ne'erav

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, psych-mentalhealth, maaseh-merkavah

ג) ומתעסק במעשה מרכבה, מי אמר לו, אלימא משום שגיונות לימא שאר מילי אורייתא שגם בהם שייך שגגה:

https://www.sefaria.org/Or_Neerav,_PART_I_4.15

In this section of אור נערב the רמק goes back and forth on the word שגיונות.

In sefaria they translate it as "errors."

Now in hebrew שגיאות is errors and שיגעון is insanity. But it would appear they come from the same root. When I type in the various permutations of the words used in that section some words of insanity come up in Google Translate. Examples include "foible" or "fixed idea."

Is it possible to read this section translating that word as "insanity" rather than errors?

If my memory serves me correctly an esteemed scholar I studied with read it like that.

I will also add that the reading of the Ramak makes more sense as some form of insanity rather than errors.